# Submit form to a non default page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webforms, action

I solved this problem in another instance by making some workaround but I want to get it clear this time as I understand my problem better.

My asp.net net page has a search functionality that searches the database based on 5 fields. The result is displayed in the gridview. The gridview is editable and I can update values. The problem is if I want to update multiple values, gridview won't allow it. So I included an extra column for checkbox. I have added a footer which has link to update all checked records.

Ok so here is the problem? How do I send the whole gridview to another page where I can capture the gridview values?

By default the page is submitted onto itself. If I change the default action page, the whole gridview and search, nothing will work.

So how do I submit the whole page (or part of it) to a different page other than the default action script?

Comment: Can you just change the "action" attribute of your `<form>` to submit to a different destination page?

Comment: Nothing nothing on that page will work. Edit, find, everything will be posted to the new page.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just a thought =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this specifically with a gridview, but I think a Cross Page PostBack should work. I have a search feature on my website as well and this is what I use.

Set the PostBackUrl of the Button that is causing the PostBack to the Destination page. 
Let’s assume your source page is search.aspx and your destination page is SearchResult.aspx

Inside search.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"  CssClass="right" 
    ValidationGroup = "Search"
    PostBackUrl="~/SearchResult.aspx"
    onclick="btnSearch_Click"/>
```

The form will be posted to SearchResult.aspx. Inside SearchResult.aspx, you add this directive:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Search.aspx"  %>
```

And in the code behind, you can acess any control like this:

```
PreviousPage.<mycontrol>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `Session`? Just add the `DataSource`, or the `Gridview` itself to the `Session` and load it in the other Page and then `Dispose()` it.

Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

I have accomplished this in the past through [Cross-Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx). This is how I did it now for testing purposes:

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" PostBackUrl="SearchResult.aspx" />
```

SearchResult.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            if (Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1") != null)
            {
                GridView grid = (GridView)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
                grid.ID = "myGrid";
                this.form1.Controls.Add(grid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I used session in my other work around. But I am wondering, if there is a proper way of doing it. Since this is ASP.NET related, I would like someone answer it. Lets say Session is one solution, but is there any other way?